# Reading a sqlite3.Binary object with numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy, sqlite

I have a text file that containes a large string that was originally a binary blob in an SQL column. I would like to read the data using `numpy.genfromtxt` and convert the text to a 1D numpy array and then to a binary blob to be imported later into SQL using the converters parameter:

```
       np.genfromtxt(data, delimiter='\t',
              dtype = [ ("a", 'f8'), ("b", 'U100'), ("c", 'f8') ],
              converters = {1: lambda x: sqlite3.Binary(
                     np.fromstring(x, dtype='f4', sep=' '))})
```

And the imput file would be something like this:

1.0\t1.0 2.0 3.0\t1.0

However this gives the error message:

```
  File "./import_sql.py", line 25, in <module>
    converters = {19: lambda x: sqlite3.Binary(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1742, in genfromtxt
    rows = np.array(data, dtype=[('', _) for _ in dtype_flat])
ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence
```

I would like to have genfromtxt return an array where the first and third columns will contain float values and the second column contains sqlite3.Binary blob of data with a 1D numpy array.

This does not work so I have read the data into a large string in the output from genfromtxt and then process it before writing the data to the database. Is it possible to include a sqlite3.Binary object into a numpy array?

Comment: It would help if you prepare and show some small sample input data, because the call you show tries to treat column 19 as space delimited array in an already whitespace delimited row.  Which obviously can't work. The sample should be smaller than 19 columns but enough to show the problem and verify it actually has the problem. Then the expected output for the sample input would be a helpful add on to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to switch the type of column `b` from type `'U100'` to `object`, then it should work.